# HTTP Status: 500 - Server Error while creating neo4j HA cluster

Tags: neo4j, high-availability

While creating Neo4j HA cluster using 2 machines, after making necessary changes and starting neo4j service, an authentication card pops up in the slave neo4j web UI, asking for username and password, even though security is disabled in the neo4j-server.properties file of both instances.

For entering a wrong password, it shows the error invalid username or password, however throws an error 'HTTP Status: 500 - Server Error' for entering the right password.

The console.log shows a different picture though:

```
ERROR Failed to start transaction. Timeout waiting for database to become available and allow new transactions. Waited 2m. 1 reasons for blocking: High Availability member state not ready.
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Timeout waiting for database to become available and allow new transactions. Waited 2m. 1 reasons for blocking: High Availability member state not ready.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.checkAvailability(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:349)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTx(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:298)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalPeriodTransactionMessContainer.newTransaction(TransitionalPeriodTransactionMessContainer.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.ensureActiveTransaction(TransactionHandle.java:242)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$2.write(TransactionalService.java:211)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: When authentication is disabled in `neo4j-server.properties` and you've restarted the instance, Neo4j browser will never ask for credentials. Obviousyly you're doing something badly wrong here. Maybe follow this guide verbosely: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks , it was something that i missed upon. I hadn't uncommented the lines, 'ha.server' and 'ha.cluster_server'. Its done now, and works well.

Answer (score 1):

What the message says, the cluster is not ready yet.

> Timeout waiting for database to become available and allow new
>   transactions. Waited 2m. 1 reasons for blocking: High Availability
>   member state not ready. org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException:
>   Timeout waiting for database to become available and allow new
>   transactions. Waited 2m. 1 reasons for blocking: High Availability
>   member state not ready.

You need a quorum of at least 3 machines to run a cluster.

Comment: Thanks , it was something that i missed upon. I hadn't uncommented the lines, 'ha.server' and 'ha.cluster_server'. Its done now, and works well.